# Error in predict.svm:constant. Cannot scale data

Tags: r

I get my dataset from the below function:

```
dataGenerator<-function(size){
        x <- runif( size,1,10)
        y <- runif( size,1,10)
        data.frame(X=x,Y=y)
}
```

And then i try to add two columns to it using this code

```
smiller<-function(points){

  for(i in i:nrow(points)){
    if(6<points[i,1] & points[i,1]<7 & 6<points[i,2] & points[i,2]<7)
      points["scores"] <- as.vector((points[i,1]-7)^2+(points[i,2]-7)^2)
    else
      points["scores"] <- as.vector((points[i,1]-5)^2+(points[i,2]-5)^2-9)
  }
  points["class"]<-(as.vector(  points$scores<0 ))
  points
}
```

here is the call

```
train <-smiller(  dataGenerator(100))
```

and at the end i try to leran it using  a svm classifier on it.

```
   model <- svm(class ~ . , train,type = "C",kernel = "linear")
```

but it complains with:

```
Variable(s) �scores� constant. Cannot scale data.
 Show Traceback
Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : Model is empty!
```

Comment: Using `summary(train)` you can see that in your `train` data.frame variables "class" and "scores" have zero variability.

Comment: what do you mean by `zero variability`?
How can i fix it?

Comment: With "zero variability" I mean "constant". They have the same value in the 100 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, there are some problems with your `smiller` function.
Below you can find a version of your code with some (hopefully correct) changes.

```
dataGenerator <- function(size) {
    x <- runif( size,1,10)
    y <- runif( size,1,10)
    data.frame(X=x,Y=y)
}

smiller <- function(points){
  for(i in 1:nrow(points)){
   if(6<points[i,1] & points[i,1]<7 & 6<points[i,2] & points[i,2]<7)
    points[i,"scores"] <- as.vector((points[i,1]-7)^2+(points[i,2]-7)^2)
   else
    points[i,"scores"] <- as.vector((points[i,1]-5)^2+(points[i,2]-5)^2-9)
  }
 points["class"]<-(as.vector(points$scores<0))
 points
}

train <- smiller(dataGenerator(100))

library(e1071)
model <- svm(class ~ . , train, type = "C", kernel = "linear")
print(model)
```

The result is:

```
Call:
svm(formula = class ~ ., data = train, type = "C", kernel = "linear")

Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  C-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  linear 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.3333333 

Number of Support Vectors:  25
```

Comment: can you explain, what you have changed?